# Keep getting this error when I build react native (0.64) app: ld: library not found for -lFBReactNativeSpec

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I'm using m1 macbook and trying to run the app that was built 3 years ago. (At that time, I used intel macbook)
These are my versions for react and react-native:

```
"react": "^17.0.0",
"react-native": "^0.64.0",
```

I tried npx react-native link, changing podfile, and other methods on the internet but I'm keep getting "ld: library not found for -lFBReactNativeSpec" error when I try yarn ios or build from xcode.
If anyone know how to resolve this, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

By now I just removed `libFBReactNativeSpec.a` from the target's Link Binary With Libraries list, and it builds successfully, let's see if I'm gonna have problems later in runtime